# Meteor, stub method and meteor methods

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using meteor,
and I have a handlebar tag in my html

```
{{displayResult}}
```

in my client side JS file I write the helpers and stub method like this

**Helper Function**
**EDIT**

```
displayResult:function(){
    var abc;
    var apiResultDependency = new Deps.Dependency();  
    Meteor.call('apiresult',function(e,result){
   abc=result;
   apiResultDependency.changed();                                           
    });                                     
                                                console.log(abc);                                                  
                                             console.log(result);

apiResultDependency.depend();
    return abc;//returning nothing
}
```

**Stub Method**

```
Meteor.startup(function(){              
    return Meteor.methods({
        apiresult:function(){
            console.log("loading...");
        }
    });
});
```

and my server code connecting with one API and delaying results, my code is

```
apiresult:function(){
  var response = returnAllResult();//this gets the result from outside func. working good
  return response;
}
```

I want to take the result from server side function and I want to display in the html file
how to receive and display it. I'm not getting anything in my webpage. In my console it is printing the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your template does not rerender when the data arrives from the server. The easiest way to solve this is to use reactive datasource pattern (look [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency)), so in your client side code you would need to add something like:

```
var apiResultDependency = new Deps.Dependency();
var abc;
```

and your helper may look like this:

```
displayResult: function() {
  if (abc === undefined) {
    Meteor.call('apiresult', function(e,result) {
      abc = result; // make sure this is not undefined to prevent infinite loop
      apiResultDependency.changed();
    });
  }
  apiResultDependency.depend();
  return abc;
}
```

Comment: That's the main problem when i call server side method it first sets the abc variable as undefined. i'm running through loop now.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Have you check my suggestion though? I am pretty much sure this should work fine.

Comment: i wrote a stub method which returns "loading.." string and it didn't work and still the result is returning undefined value.how to over come it.